# How do you generate Modules Models in ZF and Doctrine?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, models

I am trying to figure out how do you generate models for modules in ZF? My logic could be flawed, but here is the setup:

I have a ZF Structure setup for modules. I have a Blog Module and a Game Module. I wish for both of these systems to be independent of each other, but share the same common modules, such as user accounts, they would be hosted under separate databases IE a `Blog Database` and a `Game Database` and a `Core database`. So my structure would look like:

```
ZF /
 - applications /
   - configs
   - controllers
   - models
      User.php
   - modules
     - blog
       - controllers
       - models
          Blog.php
       - views
     - games
       - controllers
       - models
          Games.php
       - views
   - views
```

I am just a bit confused on how you can get doctrine to generate the models for individual modules. I could be looking at this completely wrong, if anyone can shed some insight I would totally appreciate it, short of manually doing it. Back to trying to do some more research for it see if I can find the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK  you can't generate them in your way  :( , sorry for that  .
i ran into same problem once before and i think the best solution is to generate the Models out of the application folder and put them into the Library folder so the structure would be

```
ZF /
 - applications /
   - configs
   - controllers
   - models
   - modules
     - blog
       - controllers
       - models
       - views
     - games
       - controllers
       - models
       - views
   - views
 -library/
   -your_custom_namespace 
        -Model
          User.php
          Blog.php
          Games.php
```

so all of your model would have the same prefix + save the time and pain of manually editing each generated model to fit to its namespace .

down below my doctrine cli

```
<?php
echo "Hello Tawfek ! , Howdy ?? \n";
/**
 * Doctrine CLI
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('ROOT_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../"));
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');
//Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '../library',get_include_path(), "/home/Sites/site/library/" )));
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

// Read in the application.ini bootstrap for Doctrine
$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap('doctrine');

// Create the configuration array
$config = $application->getOption('doctrine');
// (Note you can have all of these in application.ini aswell)
$config['generate_models_options'] = array(
    // Define the PHPDoc Block in the generated classes
    'phpDocPackage'         =>'site',
    'phpDocSubpackage'      =>'Models',
    'phpDocName'            =>'Your Name Goes here',
    'phpDocEmail'           =>'Your Email',
    'phpDocVersion'         =>'1.0',
    // Define whats what and named how, where.
    'suffix'                => '.php',
    'pearStyle'             => true,
    'baseClassPrefix'       => 'Base_',
    // Unless you have created a custom class or want Default_Model_Base_Abstract
    'baseClassName'         => 'Doctrine_Record',
    // Leave this empty as specifying 'Base' will create Base/Base
    'baseClassesDirectory'  => NULL,
    // Should make it Zend Framework friendly AFAIK
    'classPrefix'           => 'Dagho_Model_',
    'classPrefixFiles'      => false,
    'generateBaseClasses'   => true,
    'generateTableClasses'  => false,
    'packagesPath'          =>  APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Dagho/Model" ,
    'packagesFolderName'    => 'packages',

);

$cli = new Doctrine_Cli($config);
$cli->run($_SERVER['argv']);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, kind of what I figured. I have some other ideas before I completely give it up about my own custom `Doctrine_Cli`. But thanks for confirming this for me. Appreciate it.